# Angular Select initial value not selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have a strange problem with data-binding on select.

Here are the definitions of my objects :

```
brands =
[
    {
        $$hashKey: "object:18"
        firm: Object
        id: 242
        name: " CONTAGEL "
        regex: null
    },
    ...
]

products = 
[
    {
        $$hashKey: "object:7"
        brand: 
        {
            $$hashKey: "object:613"
            firm: Object
            id: 32
            name: "Level Junior Solaire"
            regex: null
        }
        label: "Level Junior Solaire - LL LEJUS1501"
        productCode: "01646554"
    },
    ...
]
```

I have a list of brand and a list of products. Each product have a brand (pulled from the brand array).

I want to display the list of product with a select for changing the brand.

```
<div ng-repeat="p in products">
    Product : {{p.productCode}} 
    <select ng-model="p.brand" ng-options="b as b.name for b in brands">
</div>
```

The option list is filled with the brand list but not any value is selected. And when i change the value of the select, it changes the brand of the product.

So I don't understand what I have missed.

Comment: the object that is there in the list and of the model does not match hence its not getting pre selected

Comment: @neda What is different ?

Comment: Try use [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) - `<select ng-model="p.brand" ng-options="b as b.name for b in brands track by brands.name"></select>`

Comment: @user3335966 never use `as` with `track by`.  They are not designed to work together.

Comment: @Mike what is the difference between track by and as ? I was thinking that `as` had the behavior of `track by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your `ng-options`.  `ng-model` on select boxes uses references, so unless the object is the same reference, it's not going to be selected by default.  In your case, it's a new object and therefore *not* the same reference, so in `ng-model`'s eyes, it's not a match.  Use `track by` to match on the id.

```
ng-options="b.name for b in brands track by b.id"
```

Comment: Why the references are differents ? the brand value in prodcuts object came from the brand list.

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code, what you've provided in your original post doesn't show where the data is coming from or how it gets handled.

Comment: I have found. I have forgotten a case where brand is given by an ajax call... Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

The brand object from Brands variable is different from the brand object of the products variable as you can see in your example.

Comment: What is the difference ?

Comment: {
        $$hashKey: "object:18"
        firm: Object
        id: 242
        name: " CONTAGEL "
        regex: null
    }

is different from

{
            $$hashKey: "object:613"
            firm: Object
            id: 32
            name: "Level Junior Solaire"
            regex: null
        }

So, when you are trying to set the default option to the model, since all the data in both the objects are different, it would not get set.

But if you donot want angular to check for the entire object and if you want to go by name, check the comment by Mike, that would solve it.

Comment: I have puted example to show the structure of objects. Like indicated by "..." at the end of each array.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I was trying to explain how it works. So none of your objects from products must have matched with any of the objects from Brands.